# Google fonts are showing up inconsistently

Tags: css, fonts

I'm building this website where I am using both Cormorant Garamond and Roboto Slab as my fonts. Only problem is that they are only showing up in the header, and even when I specify the font that I want to use in specific CSS tags, it won't show up at all.

I want to first show the HTML and the CSS that I'm using to make sure it's not a simple mistake.

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond' serif;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200"/>
<h2>Here is a Heading</h2>
```

Here's a screenshot for reference:

[image: Screenshot of my Problem.]

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `,` before the `serif` part in your css.

Here is the working code:

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.Card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  background: pink
}

img {
  width: 100vh;
  height: auto
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="Card">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/200?image=0" />
  <h2>Jester</h2>
  <h3>Prints available upon request.</h3>
</div>
```

Hope it Helps.

Peace .

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify different fonts for each tag

```css
h2 {
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cormorant+Garamond|Roboto+Slab" rel="stylesheet">


<h2>This is Cormorant Garamond font</h2>

<h3>This is Roboto Slab font</h3>
```